# Reading raw serial data in Matlab

Tags: matlab, callback, serial-port

I'm trying to read some raw telemetry data via serial. Each message terminates with `\r\n` and there are 4 kinds of messages.

I setup the port like this:

```
if exist('s')
    fclose(s);
    delete(s);
    clear s;
end

s = serial('/dev/ttyS99');
s.BaudRate = 57600;
s.BytesAvailableFcnMode = 'terminator';
s.Terminator = 'CR/LF';
s.DataBits = 8;
s.Parity = 'none';
s.StopBits = 1;

s.BytesAvailableFcn = @serial_callback;
s.OutputEmptyFcn = @serial_callback;

fopen(s);
```

For the calback, i wrote a simple function

```
function serial_callback(obj, event)
if (obj.BytesAvailable > 0)
    [serial_out, count] = fscanf(obj);
    disp(count)
    end

end
end
```

Using `fscanf`, I get random message lengths. For instance, I am searching for a message with length 42, and it only retrieves messages with length near that value (40, 43, 46...).

I i use `fread` with unspecified size, I allways get a full 512 bytes buffer. If I specify the size in `fread` with `get(obj, 'BytesAvailable)`, it degenerates in the sizes of `fscanf`, i.e., totally random.

So, am I doing something wrong, is matlab bad for parsing serial data...?

P.S. I am getting something like 40 messages of 20~40 bytes per second.

Comment: The serial port has no notion of your message boundaries, so you'll likely have to read data and accumulate it until you get to a message boundary.

Answer (score 0):

1. Call the callback function everytime a `\r\n` has been received, using [`BytesAvailableFcnMode`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_external/bytesavailablefcnmode.html) to configure. `fscanf` should only be called when a line is completely received by the buffer.
2. Use [`fgets`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgets.html) or [`fgetl`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/fgetl.html) to read *one line* from file. This will keep all things after the first `\r\n` in the buffer. I don't have a serial port nor a Tek so I can't verify this to be working for serial ports.
3. Probably you need a `while` loop to read all lines in the buffer. Again I'm not sure how `serial` does callback but it's unlikely to continuously triggering callback function when there's nothing newly arrived after callback has been called.