# Continuous read of two virtual COM ports within same script

Tags: matlab

I have two commercial devices both connected to my PC as virtual COM ports via USB. Each device transmits data at a set rate (not defined by me). I am not able to send a 'print' command and receive the data, I can only retrieve it as it comes in.

I am able to access and use the data of each device individually, but I was wondering how two devices can be handled if both sampling rates differ (1 Hz vs. 2 Hz)?

Is there an interrupt based method that I could use to wait for each port to receive a new value and grab it as they come in instead of putting everything in a while loop and continuously check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of searching and playing around with my code, I figured out how to get this working. Big thanks to this thread for pointing me in the right direction: [Reading raw serial data in Matlab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940876/reading-raw-serial-data-in-matlab)

Instead of using fscanf or fgets for both devices within the while loop, which caused data lag issues because of different sampling rates, I created two function files for each device read and used callbacks within the main while loop to check for BytesAvailableFcn status.

Below is a thorough example.

-----------------------main_file.m-----------------------

```
% Create global arrays for main and function scripts visibility
global device1_array;
global device2_array;

% Create COM port variables for each device
s_device1 = serial('COM2', 'BaudRate', 19200, 'DataBits', 8, 'Parity', 'none', 'StopBits', 1, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode', 'terminator');
s_device2 = serial('COM3', 'BaudRate', 9600, 'DataBits', 8, 'Parity', 'none', 'StopBits', 1, 'BytesAvailableFcnMode', 'terminator');

% Open COM ports
fopen(s_device1);
fopen(s_device2);

% Create data figure and stop button to exit loop
fig = figure(1);
tb = uicontrol(fig, 'Style', 'togglebutton', 'String', 'Stop');
drawnow;

while(1)

    % Check for button click to exit loop
    drawnow;
    if (get(tb, 'Value')==1); break; end

    % Callbacks to check when data is ready from either device
    s_device1.BytesAvailableFcn = @device1_serial_callback;
    s_device2.BytesAvailableFcn = @device2_serial_callback;

    % Plot variables
    subplot(2, 1, 1);
    plot(device1_array);    
    subplot(2, 1, 2);
    plot(device2_array);

end

% Close COM ports
fclose(s_device1);
fclose(s_device2);

% Delete COM port variables
delete(s_device1);
delete(s_device2);
```

-----------------------device1_serial_callback.m-----------------------

```
function device1_serial_callback(obj, event)
    global device1_array;

    if (obj.BytesAvailable > 0)

        device1_data = fgets(obj); % likely will need to process raw data
        device1_array = [device1_array device1_data];

    end

end
```

-----------------------device2_serial_callback.m-----------------------

```
function device2_serial_callback(obj, event)
    global device2_array;

    if (obj.BytesAvailable > 0)

        device2_data = fgets(obj); % likely will need to process raw data
        device2_array = [device2_array device2_data];

    end

end
```